# model a with opencv

Tags: opencv, noobs

I got a camera, a model A and a 8gig sd card and no idea what i'm doing

I tried writing the noobs full image to the disk but when i plug it into the montior and power it on I get nothing

Is there an image that has opencv on it already?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific with your question please, such as Model/Type of SD card (not all work well with RPi), are you getting lights on the Pi board?

Comment: tell us more about LED lights on the side of the board, do they blink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out

I saw a video where you had to use win32 disk imager to image the sd card

I renamed the noob.zip to noob.bin and used the utility to create the "boot" disk

upon further review you just need to format and drop the files on the sd card

it boots fine now

thanks